# width: 100% and white-space: nowrap results in input elements going over width of parent element

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Here's my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2" style="white-space: nowrap">Field 1: <input type="text" name="member_name" style="width: 100%"/></td>
        <td colspan="2" style="white-space: nowrap">Field 2: <input type="text" name="member_name2" style="width: 100%"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
        <td>State: <select name="state">
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            </select></td>
        <td>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone2" /></td>
        <td>State: <select name="state2">
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is that the `<td>` elements with white-space set to nowrap extend into the neighboring `<td>`'s, presumably because of the `width: 100%` bit in the child `<input>`.

Any ideas as to how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can place a `div` inside `td`.
- use `flex` to align the elements.
- No need of using `white-space` and `width: 100%`

```css
.form-control {
  display: flex;
}
.form-control input {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div class="form-control">
            <label>Field 1: </label>
            <input type="text" name="member_name"/>
          </div>
        </td>
        <td colspan="2">
          <div class="form-control">
            <label>Field 2: </label>
            <input type="text" name="member_name"/>
          </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone" /></td>
        <td>State: <select name="state">
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            </select></td>
        <td>Phone: <input type="text" name="phone2" /></td>
        <td>State: <select name="state2">
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
            </select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```